# JAVA Simple slot machine loop

Tags: java, loops

I have an assignment due that requires me to create a slot machine program that will continue to run until either the user runs out of money or presses zero. I can't figure out what kind of loop and what variables to use for this loop in order to get this to work. Currently I have all of the if statements that I need for the rest of the program but what kind of loop is giving me trouble. I thought a while loop would be the way to go but every time I implement a while loop the program wouldn't stop executing.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SlotMachine {
public static final int BALANCE=10;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int bet, remBal=0,winnings1,winnings2;
    int slot1, slot2, slot3;

    Random generator = new Random();
    System.out.println("Starting Balance = $10:00");
    Scanner kbd=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a bet $");
    bet=kbd.nextInt();

    if (bet>0&&bet<BALANCE){
        slot1 = generator.nextInt(10);
        slot2 = generator.nextInt(10);
        slot3 = generator.nextInt(10);
        slot1 = 3;
        slot2 = 3;
        slot3 = 3;
        System.out.println(slot1+" "+slot2+" "+slot3);
        if(slot1==slot2&&slot2==slot3&&slot1==slot3){
            System.out.println("You win: "+(double)(slot1+1)*bet);
            winnings1=(slot1+1)*bet;
            remBal=BALANCE-bet+winnings1;
        }else if (slot1==slot2||slot2==slot3){
            System.out.println("You win: "+(double)(slot2*bet)/2);
            winnings2=(slot2*bet)/2;
            remBal=BALANCE-bet+winnings2;
        }else{
            System.out.println("Balance "+(double)(BALANCE-bet));
        }
    }else if(bet==0){
        System.out.println("You earned"+remBal);

    }kbd.close();
}
```

}

Comment: you mention the loop never ends. what is the condition you're setting on your while loop?

Comment: I had my while loop at while (bet!=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the code requesting a bet is outside the block processing it. If you turn that into a `while` loop then you'll never ask the user for another bet; hence the infinite loop.

What you probably want is a `do-while` loop. This means the code to request a bet is executed at least once and the test is checked at the end of the block rather than the start.

So the structure of your code should be:

```
do {
    // ask for bet
    if (bet > 0) {
        // process bet
    }
} while (bet > 0 && balance > 0);
// print out results
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you. The fact that my bet was outside of the loop went over my head completely and I couldn't figure out why the loop didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code

```
    System.out.println("Starting Balance = $10:00");
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a bet $");
    bet = kbd.nextInt();

    while (bet != 0) {
        // you code
        System.out.print("Enter a bet $");
        bet = kbd.nextInt();
    }
    kbd.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class SlotMachine {
public static final int BALANCE=10;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int bet, remBal=BALANCE,winnings1,winnings2;
    int slot1, slot2, slot3;


Random generator = new Random();
System.out.println("Starting Balance = $10:00");
Scanner kbd=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a bet $");
bet=kbd.nextInt();

    while (bet>0 && bet<remBal){
        //Your code for checking wins
        bet = kbd.nextInt();
    }
kbd.close();
}
```